# NoProviderError using CanActivate in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular 2 with Router 3.0.0-aplha.8.

I'm trying to use CanActivate function to check if an user is authenticated. I have an AuthGuard that implements CanActivate, for now I only return true.

**route.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard'

import { SecurityComponent } from './security/security.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './admin/admin.dashboard.component';


export const mainRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: '', component: SecurityComponent,  },
{ path: 'admin', component: AdminDashboardComponent, terminal: true, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }]

export const MAIN_ROUTER_PROVIDER = provideRouter(mainRoutes);
```

**auth-guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
   CanActivate,
   Router,
   ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
       return true;
   }
}
```

When I try to access "/admin" (AdminDashboardComponent), I'm getting this error:

[image]

I have no idea what is happening. Someone has any idea?

Thanks
Iván

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if you change `MAIN_ROUTER_PROVIDER` to

```
export const MAIN_ROUTER_PROVIDER = [provideRouter(mainRoutes), AuthGuard];
```

it should work.

Comment: Thank you!! I was really stuck. What's the difference between your answer and the answer from @ed-morales. Could you tell me what is the best practice??

Thanks again!

Comment: He has one more level of abstraction otherwise its the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bootstrap the guards too, so they can be used properly:

```
export const AUTH_PROVIDERS = [AuthGuard];
```

and then

```
export const MAIN_ROUTER_PROVIDER = [
  provideRouter(mainRoutes),
  AUTH_PROVIDERS,
];
```

more info here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Answer (score 1):

You need to bootstrap AuthGuard as well. Update your route provider as below

`export const MAIN_ROUTER_PROVIDER = [provideRouter(mainRoutes), AuthGuard]`

And adjust the bootstrap function to include this list `bootstrap(appcomp,MAIN_ROUTER_PROVIDER)`