# "No provider for AuthGuard!" using CanActivate in Angular 2

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-routing

**EDIT :** Obviously this is outdated, now you provide your guard at the `providers` array in an NgModule. Watch other answers or official documentation for more information.

- bootstrapping on a component is outdated
- `provideRouter()` is outdated as well

---

---

I'm trying to setup Authentication in my project, using a login and AuthGuard from the Angular2 guide : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

I'm using the release :  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1".

I'll try to explain as much as possible, feel free to tell me if you need more details.

---

I have my **main.ts** file which boostraps the app with the following code :

```
bootstrap(MasterComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    MenuService
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I load the MasterComponent, which loads a Header containing buttons that allow me to navigate through my app and it also contains my main  for now.

I'm following the guide to make my app work the same way, with the following **app.routes.ts** :

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...LoginRoutes,
    ...MasterRoutes
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes),
    AUTH_PROVIDERS
];
```

And the **login.routes.ts** from the guide, which defines my AuthGuard :

```
export const LoginRoutes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

export const AUTH_PROVIDERS = [AuthGuard, AuthService];
```

my Master component has its own route definition, which also contains the guard I'm trying to setup. **master.routes.ts** :

```
export const MasterRoutes : RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/accueil', pathMatch: 'full' },

    {
        path: 'accueil',
        component: AccueilComponent
    },

    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

And I'm using the same files as the guide, which are **auth.guard.ts**, **auth.service.ts**, **login.component.ts** and **login.routes.ts**.

---

In my **header.component.ts** file, when I try to access any routes, it's working just fine, but when I try to access the guarded path (/dashboard), I get the **No provider for AuthGuard!** error.

I saw the recent post with the same issue as mine ([NoProviderError using CanActivate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129212/noprovidererror-using-canactivate-in-angular-2/38129422#38129422)), but to me the guard is bootstraped correctly up to the **main.ts** file, so my router should know which routes should be provided with the AuthGuard right ?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks !

Comment: Did you import `AuthGuard` into `master.routes.ts` and `login.routes.ts`?

Comment: Yes, I did import them correctly.
I did not mention it, but I manually navigate to the route because I wanted to link on a <button> using  **this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);**

Comment: Does `AuthGuard` have constructor parameters? Does it have the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Comment: Yes, I am using the auth.guard.ts file from the guide, with the authService and the router in DI in the constructor.
There is also the decorator.
It's the exact same file as the **app/auth.guard.ts (v.2)** from the guide

Comment: If you remove `canActivate: [AuthGuard]`, is routing working?

Comment: Yes, it's working correctly, although I noticed I get the following warning : 
**'AccueilComponent' not found in precompile array.** (and the same warning for DashboardComponent when I navigate by clicking on my button)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144547/in-angular2-rc4-how-do-i-add-components-to-the-precompile-array/38144580#38144580

Comment: I'm out of ideas about `AuthGuard` though.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can clear the warnings :-)
Well, there must be a bug somwhere, because all the routes are working fine, and I just followed the guide up to the canActivate Milestone...

Comment: You can try to reproduce in Plunker then I can have a look https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Weird thing is that my company's firewall is actually blocking the plunkr links, so I may need a bit of time... I'll edit this comment with a working plunkr hopefully

Comment: Just add a comment when you provide the plunker link so I get notified.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/iDghZJNl1hL7UQM1MEsC?p=preview

I don't get it... It works on the plunker even though it's the exact same thing without the css and the images... I guess I have to search in my own code the reason...

Comment: It might be an issue with your configuration.

Comment: Yeah found it... geez... to lose 2 hours over this...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Gunter, even though it was nothing much in the end...

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it was only a typo in an import...

I was typing

> import { AuthGuard } from './../Authentification/auth.guard';

instead of

> import { AuthGuard } from './../authentification/auth.guard';

making it not working but at the same time not displaying me any error...

(sadface)

Comment: Thats why it is recommended to use typescript aware editor like Visual studio code ( its the best ).

Comment: Yes, I've been using VS 2015 but clearly, it's not as good as Visual Code.

Comment: I faced same kind of issue, finally found the issue is the import path is case sensitive

Answer (score 86):

I had this same issue after going through the Route Guards section of Routing and Authorization tutorial on the Angular website https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html, it is section 5.

I am adding AuthGuard to one of my main routes and not to child routes like the tutorial shows.

I fixed it by added AuthGuard to my list of providers in my app.module.ts file, so that file now looks like this:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-gaurd.service';

import { AnotherPageComponent } from './another-page/another-page.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    JsonpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    AnotherPageComponent
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I have gone back through the tutorial and in their `app.module.ts` file, they do not add `AuthGuard` to the providers, not sure why.

Comment: it is kind of interesting that I did not need to add guards to providers, and the books I am reading asks to, I have no idea why my app is working without it! that is why I have found this question, my app works, and I have not add to the providers, I am using lazy load.

Answer (score 34):

Try to add

`@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})`

no need to add to module provider.

Answer (score 18):

Also, don't fall into the trap of using a literal for the guard class inside your routing configuration, just because some blog articles do:

```
{ path: 'whatever', component: WhatEverComponent, canActivate: ['WhatEverGuard'] }
```

is not going to work (`No provider for...`), instead, use the class directly:

```
{ path: 'whatever', component: WhatEverComponent, canActivate: [WhatEverGuard] }
```

Another hint, when lazy loading components, the guard is applied in the routing configuration of the parent component, not in the routing configuration of the lazy loaded component.

Comment: I put WhatEverGuard into single quotes, and it showed me No provider .. that was so annoying

Comment: Me too. I had:

canActivate: [ 'AuthGuard', AuthGuard ]

As soon as I removed the literal it worked.

Comment: oh my God, you genius! thank you for this answer, the stupid tutorial I was following has used single quotes exactly like you describe!

Answer (score 12):

For those who still have this error - don't forget to include your AuthGuard service or class to main bootstrap function.
And don't forget to import this service before bootstrap runs.

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  appRouterProviders,
  AuthGuard
]);
```

Angular 2 team did not mention this in main router docs, and it took couple of hours for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is further down in the tutorial.  See the file listings in the "Add the LoginComponent" topic under the "Component-less route:..." section in  "Milestone 5: Route Guards".  It shows AuthGuard and AuthService being imported and added to the providers array in login-routing.module.ts, and then that module being imported into app.module.ts.

login-routing.module.ts

```
  ...
    import { AuthGuard }            from './auth-guard.service';
    import { AuthService }          from './auth.service';
    ...
    @NgModule({
    ...
      providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        AuthService
      ]
    })
    export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { LoginRoutingModule }      from './login-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    LoginRoutingModule,
    ...    
  ],
  ...
  providers: [
    DialogService
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was stuck on the tutorial and this helped a lot.  I thought that they should be in the appModule, but they aren't in the final version of the code and I couldn't figure out how it worked without them.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue when I was following a tutorial. I tried most of the answer here but not getting any success. Then I tried the silly way like putting the AuthGuard before the other services in the provider and it works.

```
// app.module.ts

 .. 
 providers: [
   AuthGuard,
   UserService,
   ProjectService
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you got the solution as it was due to syntax issue. I just wanted to share this info.

we need to provide the AuthGaudSerivce as provider in only that module that correspond to respective route. No need to provide in main module or root module as main module will automatically load all the given sub module.This helps in keeping the code modular and encapsulated.

for example, suppose we have below scenario

```
1. we have module m1
2. we have route m1r in module m1
3. route m1r has 2 route r1 and r2
4. we want to protect r1 using authGaurd
5. finally we have main module that is dependent on sub module m1
```

Below is just prototype, not the actual code for understanding purpose

```
//m1.ts    
import {AuthGaurd} from './auth.gaurd.service'
import {m1r} from './m1r'
    @NgModule(
     imports: [m1r],
     providers: [AuthGaurd]
    )
    export class m1{
    }

//m1r.ts
import {AuthGaurd} from './auth.gaurd.service'
const authRoute = [
 {path: '/r1', component: 'authComponent', canActivate: [AuthGaurd]},
 {path: '/r2', component: 'other'}
]
export authRoute

//main.module.ts
import {m1} from ''
import {mainComponent} from ''
@NgModule({
  imports: [m1],
  bootstrap: [mainComponent]
  })
export class MainModule{}
```

Comment: You missed AuthGuard

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution, and how fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

Importing both `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule` helped me.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can try import AuthGuard in provider of that module and then import it in the routing component-routing.module.ts file also

```
@NgModule({
providers: [
    AuthGuard
  ],})
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had setup my Routes incorrectly:

**WRONG**

```
const routes: Routes = 
[
  { 
    path: 'my-path', 
    component: MyComponent, 
    resolve: { myList: MyListResolver, canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ] } 
  },
];
```

Note that in this case `canActivate` was accidentally made a part of the `resolve` object.

**CORRECT**

```
const routes: Routes = 
[
  { 
     path: 'my-path', 
     component: MyComponent, 
     resolve: { myList: MyListResolver }, 
     canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ] 
  },
];
```