# What is the best practice for multiple user panels in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I will start with a new large project. I will use Angular2 but I don't know what is the best practice for a project that includes multiple user panels. I need your experiences and advice.

The project will have a landing page. On the landing page also will be a login form. If user information (username-password) are correct the user will be redirected to the panel as the type of the user. If the user an administrator, will be redirected to Admin Panel (dashboard), if not will be redirected to User Panel.

My question is:
What is the best practice to build such kind of project?

Each panel and the landing page as a separate Angular App

- localhost (landing page app)
- localhost/admin (admin panel app)
- localhost/user (user panel app)

Or
All in one Angular App that includes landing page and other user panels in it

- localhost (one app with all features)

This project will have many user types (admin, student, teacher, parent for now) and each type will have a panel with absolutely different features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your routes with the router, and you can use a guard to assign to these routes.

The guard can implement the logic you need for your several user roles.
The basic example is a guard for a route that activates only if the user is logged in. You can go further and then define your roles with a service and then guard your routes depending on the user role from the service.

The official documentation is pretty good : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean, the best practice is to build only one app with all features and securing the panels with guard. In this case, does lazy-loding help to prevent loding the user panels modules if a visitor visits only the landing page?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea to prevent some modules being loaded when not needed, but you should see the impact later on when the app becomes big. 
It's quite easy to change a route to lazy-load, that can be done afterwards.

The guard also prevent users from typing an URL manually and go into that route if they are not logged in with the correct role, so it's actually the ideal solution to your question.

Comment: Good luck with that =)
you can check this issue I had with AuthGuard : it shows a basic implementation without the service (be careful might be a bit outdated)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203647/no-provider-for-authguard-using-canactivate-in-angular-2/38205608#38205608

Comment: Thank you but I read it already while researching information about guards.:) Yes many posts, articles and videos about Angular 2 are outdated. This is an another question for me. Il

Comment: I will finish my app. After one year if I need to update some functions or features..... With nodejs, exxpress, angular, angular-cli every day someting changes